# Is there an easy way to modify a matrix to reduce its rank by 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to create a series of test matrices to unit test a Python function I have to compute the rank of a matrix in $GF(2)$. This is difficult for me because I don't have any other Python function that will do it (numpy.linalg.matrix_rank works for "regular" matrices) and I don't have a good set of test matrices already known.

Is there an easy way to modify a matrix to reduce its rank by 1? I was thinking I could create, say, a 12x12 test matrix of 0's and 1's with rank 12, then gradually reduce its rank one by one until it has rank 1, so that I have a matrix with a known rank that I can use as a test case.

Comment: If you have any $n \times n$ matrix of rank $n$, you can reduce its rank by $1$ by repeatedly deleting its rows or repeatedly deleting its columns.

Comment: Another method is to add rank 1 matrices. The matrix $a_{i,j}=x_iy_j$ is rank 1 if it is nonzero.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "deleting" = replacing by zeros?

Comment: @Jason: yes, or just deleting (so you don't have an $n \times n$ matrix anymore). It's possible this won't be a good test for your algorithm, so once you have any matrices of the desired ranks you can multiply them by a bunch of random elementary matrices or something like that to scramble them up.

Comment: I started thinking about something along the following lines. Start with a random full rank matrix. Then alter the last column so that each row has an even weight. That should reduce the rank by one. The idea was to continue by partitioning the set of columns into smaller and smaller sets, and then ensuring that within each partition all the rows have an even number of ones. But, it may be possible that the rank drops by more than one at some point :-(

Comment: Thanks all. Now I'm no longer sure whether to pursue this question further... multiplication of a $N\times k$ and $k \times N$ matrices with full rank and $k \leq N$ yields an $N\times N$ matrix with rank $k$